# AG-Grid: applyColumnState sets column positons but not the widths

Tags: ag-grid

My app will save my grid state to my mysql db onColumnResized or onDragStopped and then on remount the app will retrieve the grid state from my db and applyColumnState.The main reason for this is to save the column positions and widths for any circumstance.

applyColumnState successfully uses the state from my db to set the column positions/order but it does not set the column widths even though the new widths are present in the db saved state. For the life of me I cannot figure this out.

```
const MyTable = () => {

 // Function to save column sizes to the server
  const saveColumnState = (params) => {
  const api = params.api;
  const state = api.getColumnState();
  
  axios
    .post(apiUrl + "save-column-state",  state )
    .then((response) => {
      console.log('Column state saved successfully');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error('Error saving column state:', error);
    });
};

const onGridReady = (params) => {
    const api = params.api;

    axios.get(apiUrl + "fetch-column-state")
    .then(({ data }) => {
        api.applyColumnState({ state: columnState, applyOrder: true, });
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error("Error fetching column state:", error);
    });
};

  const handleColumnResized = (event) => {
    saveColumnState(event);
  };
    
  const handleDragStopped = async (event) => {
    saveColumnState(event);
  };

const [columnDefs, setColumnDefs] = useState([
    {
      headerName: "ID",
      field: "shopify_id",
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      hide: true,
    },
    {
      headerName: "Order #",
      field: "name",
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      hide: false,
    },
    {
      headerName: "Customer",
      field: "customer",
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      cellRenderer: CustomNameRenderer,
      hide: false,
    }, 
    {
      headerName: "Item Name",
      field: "order_items",
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      hide: false,
    },
    {
      headerName: "Quantity",
      field: "order_quantity",
      sortable: true,
      filter: true,
      hide: false,
    },
  ]);

return (
    <div>
    <div className="ag-theme-alpine" style={{ height: "500px" }}>
        <AgGridReact
            rowData={rowData}
            columnDefs={columnDefs}
            onDragStopped={(event) => handleDragStopped(event)}
            onColumnResized={handleColumnResized}
            onGridReady={onGridReady}
        />
    </div>
</div>
);
};
```

Server-side code:

```
// Endpoint for fethcing column state
app.get("/api/fetch-column-state", (req, res) => {
  const sql = "SELECT TableColumns_toship FROM Settings WHERE id = 1";

  db.query(sql, (err, result) => {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Error executing MySQL query:", err);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
    try {
      if (result && result.length > 0 && result[0].TableColumns_toship) {
        const state = JSON.parse(result[0].TableColumns_toship);
        return res.json(state);
      } else {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: "Column order not found" });
      }
    } catch (parseError) {
      console.error("Error parsing column order:", parseError);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
    }
  });
});

// Endpoint for saving column state
app.post("/api/save-column-state", (req, res) => {
  const apiData = JSON.stringify(req.body);
  const query = "UPDATE Settings SET TableColumns_toship = ? WHERE id = 1";

  db.query(query, [apiData], (error, results) => {
    if (error) throw error;
  });
  res.send('Data inserted successfully');
});
```